# unknown:ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl caught native exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

When i try to call a function from react native module it's getting me the error back unknown:ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl caught native exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke

It was working if I just print or console something the module method when I added real function with a Handler(Looper) method it's throwing the error

What's wrong with my code below ?? Or m I missing something?

Here is my Native Module Class

```
   package com.mosabeeapp;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.printer.sdk.PrinterConstants;
import com.printer.sdk.PrinterInstance;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;

public class CalendarModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    public PrinterInstance myPrinter;

    private String devicesName;
    private String devicesAddress;
    private Integer baudrate;
    private Boolean isConnected;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@" + msg.what);
            switch (msg.what) {
                case PrinterConstants.Connect.SUCCESS:
                    isConnected = true;
                    System.out.println("isConnected status:::;" + isConnected);
                    break;
                case PrinterConstants.Connect.FAILED:
                    isConnected = false;
                    System.out.println("Connection failed");
                    break;
                case PrinterConstants.Connect.CLOSED:
                    isConnected = false;
                    System.out.println("Connection closed");
                    break;
                case PrinterConstants.Connect.NODEVICE:
                    System.out.println("There is no device");
                    isConnected = false;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("0");
                    break;
                case -1:
                    System.out.println("-1");

                    break;
                case -2:
                    System.out.println("-2");

                    break;
                case -3:
                    System.out.println("-3");

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };


    CalendarModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
       super(context);
   }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
    return "CalendarModule";
    }


    @ReactMethod
    public void printData(String data) {

        System.out.println("----------buttonPrint--------");
        devicesName = "Serial device";
        devicesAddress = "/dev/ttyMT2";
        String com_baudrate = "115200";
        baudrate = Integer.parseInt(com_baudrate);

        myPrinter = PrinterInstance.getPrinterInstance(new File(devicesAddress), baudrate,0,8, mHandler);

        System.out.println("myPrinter.getCurrentStatus()-" + myPrinter.getCurrentStatus());
        boolean b = myPrinter.openConnection();
        System.out.println("-----------" + b);
        if (b && myPrinter != null) {
            System.out.println("Printer is ready");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Can not made a connection to the device");
        }

    }
}
```

And here is my full error

```
 E/unknown:ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl caught native exception
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke CalendarModule.printData
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:383)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libserial_port_sp.so" not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
        at com.printer.sdk.serial.SerialPort.<clinit>(SerialPort.java:68)
        at com.printer.sdk.PrinterInstance.<init>(PrinterInstance.java:143)
        at com.printer.sdk.PrinterInstance.getPrinterInstance(PrinterInstance.java:153)
        at com.mosabeeapp.CalendarModule.printData(CalendarModule.java:88)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke CalendarModule.printData
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:383)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libserial_port_sp.so" not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
        at com.printer.sdk.serial.SerialPort.<clinit>(SerialPort.java:68)
        at com.printer.sdk.PrinterInstance.<init>(PrinterInstance.java:143)
        at com.printer.sdk.PrinterInstance.getPrinterInstance(PrinterInstance.java:153)
        at com.mosabeeapp.CalendarModule.printData(CalendarModule.java:88)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
W/com.mosabeeapp: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;-><init>()V (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromAssetManager(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Ljava/lang/String;IZIII[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;)Z (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromBuffer(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;I[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;II)Z (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->freeze()Z (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->abortCreation()V (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Typeface;->createFromFamiliesWithDefault([Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;Ljava/lang/String;II)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
E/unknown:ReactInstanceManager: destroyRootView called
E/unknown:ReactInstanceManager: destroyRootView called, unmountReactApplication
```

Comment: Do you have a fix for this?